# Can I create my own AppDomain in a SilverLight application?

Tags: silverlight

I'm building a SilverLight application that is [dynamically loading assemblies](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-Dynamically-Loading-an-Assembly.aspx).  I would also like to be able to unload them without closing out the current SilverLight application.  However, the SilverLight AppDomain class appears to be missing a CreateDomain method.

If I can't create an AppDomain, is there an alternate mechanism to unload the assemblies ?  I have an alternate strategy if they can't be unloaded, but unloading them when they are done would be the ideal approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create additional AppDomains.  A Silverlight application runs in its own specific AppDomain and thats it.

There is no way that I know of to unload assemblies that have been loaded.  Are sure its necessary to do so?  What happens if you don't bother?

Comment: I'm loading user code that is session based.  It's possible that two users could reuse the same SilverLight application or just log off and log back in.  In practice, the add ins aren't likely to change and I don't need support assembly changes with in a SilverLight instance.  My fallback plan to just treat the loaded assemblies as a cache and only load if the aren't already loaded and track if they are active should be sufficient.  Just not as clean as I would like.

Comment: @jim: That sounds clean enough to me.

Comment: @JimRush You don't even need to track them - you simply can't load an assembly twice.